# VBA Loop Statements Excel, Matching, Counting

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I've never written an excel VBA statement before and would like some guidance.

I have a workbook with multiple sheets open.  I'm trying to match data on sheet 5 with data on sheet one and count the sum of all values that match.

Sheet 5 looks like this:

```
Company Name        Matches
Company A           57
Company B           31
Company C           20
Company D           10
```

Sheet 1 looks like this:

```
Company Name        Dollar Amount
Company A           45000
Company B           50000
Company A           60000
Company A           62000
Company D           70000
```

Sheet 1 is several hundred lines long.

Basically, I need to count the aggregate dollar amount in Sheet 1 for all instances where the company name in sheet 1 matches the company name in sheet five.

I tried a countif and countifs statements in excel. I did not receive the result I needed. I think I need to use a do until loop to calculate what I need. Unfortunately, I have no experience in this area (my expertise is law).I'm sort of stuck knowing where I need to go but not sure how to get there.

I'd appreciate any help. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you tried sumif?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your Aggregate Dollar Amount ("Total") is on column B in "Sheet 1" then on `B2` you would place the formula:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet5!A:A,Sheet1!A2,Sheet5!B:B)
```

This will add all Dollar Amounts on "Sheet 5" if the corresponding values on Column A is equal to `A2` (ie "Company A"). You can then drag down it will reference the appropriate company name. Regards,

Comment: Thank you for your help! I did not know about this function. Thank you for the learning opportunity. I appreciate your time.

Comment: My pleasure in sharing. Please consider marking my answer as correct if you feel it addresses your question. Regards,

Comment: I did. However, I need more reputation for it to publicly share. FYI. Thanks again.